# If there is a mapping of $B$ onto $A$, then $2^{|A|} \leq 2^{|B|}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse

If there is a mapping of $B$ onto $A$, then $2^{|A|} \leq 2^{|B|}$. [Hint: Given $g$ mapping $B$ onto $A$, let $f(X)=g^{-1}(X)$ for all $X \subseteq A$]

I follow the hint and obtain the function $f$. If $f$ is injective, then the statement is proven.

Question: Why does $g^{-1}$ exist in the first place? How do we know $g$ is injective? The hint given seems a bit weird.

Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Is $2^{|A|} \le 2^{|B|}$ equivalent to $|A| \le |B|$ or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @angryavian: Not necessarily. It is possible that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$, but certainly $\aleph_1\nleq\aleph_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What does $2^{*}$ notation denote if the exponent is not finite?

Comment: @angryavian: The same thing is does in the finite case. The cardinality of all the functions from a set of size $|A|$ into a set of size $2$. In this case, it's really just the cardinality of $\mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Why does $g^{−1}$ exist in the first place?

It exists for all maps. Here, it does not denote the inverse, but the pre-image map,

$$g^{-1}(X) = \{b\in B : g(b)\in X\}.$$

Now use the surjectivity of $g$ to deduce the injectivity of $g^{-1}$.

Comment: How do I differentiate between pre-image and inverse of a function?

Comment: Context. Sometimes one makes sense, sometimes the other. Here, we apply $g^{-1}$ to subsets of $A$, so the interpretation as the inverse map doesn't make sense. I sometimes wish one would use $g^{\ast}$ for the pre-image map, and $g_{\ast}$ for the direct-image map ($Y\mapsto \{ g(y) : y\in Y\}$) to avoid confucion with the inverse and the map itself, but that also has its drawbacks, since asterisks are also used for other constructions.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists a function $f:B \longrightarrow A$ such that $f$ is onto then $\lvert B \rvert \geq \lvert A \rvert$. And this means that there exists an injective function $g: A \longrightarrow B$. Now as we want to see that $2^{\lvert A \rvert} \leq 2^{\lvert B \rvert}$ it's enough to define an injective function $h: \mathcal P \left( {A} \right) \longrightarrow \mathcal P \left( {B} \right)$. Such that for $C \subseteq A$, $ h(C) :=${$ g(x) \lvert x \in C$}. Now it's not to hard to prove that this function is well defined and injective.

Comment: Here you appeal to the axiom of choice, but the general claim itself doesn't need the axiom of choice. Daniel Fischer's answer shows that.